# pytest: Using dependency injection with decorators

Tags: python, dependency-injection, pytest

At work we use a decorator `@rollback` on selected test functions which will rollback any db changes made during that test.

I've recently started using pytest's dependency injection for a few use cases, both with `@pytest.mark.parametrize(...)` and the `pytest_funcarg__XXX` hook. Unfortunately, this clashes with our decorated test functions.

How can I make this work?

My first idea was using a custom marker, say `@pytest.mark.rollback` and do something like:

```
def rollback(meth):
    """Original rollback function"""
    ...

def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    if not isinstance(item, pytest.Function):
        return
    if hasattr(item.obj, 'rollback'):
        item = rollback(item)
```

Can Would an approach like this actually work?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work fine, yes.  Seems like you are using global state to manage your database, here, right?  You might want to checkout the docs of the upcoming 2.3 release which also has a "transact" example further down this page:

http://pytest.org/dev/fixture.html

The release is due any time now and you can install the candidate with "pip install -i http://pypi.testrun.org -U pytest".